# Why do bones distort/squish my mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I have been fooling around with Blender and created a mesh along with an armature. To my eyes everything looks normal but when I rotate the arms/legs, the torso of my mesh becomes distorted. Here are some screenshots:

**T-pose (looks normal):**

[image: Model in t-pose with no rotation]

**Arm rotated (causing torso distortion):**

[image: Model with arm rotated and torso distorted]

You can see in the second picture, the rotated arm causes the torso to squish inwards. I've seen that I can set weights and apply location/scale/transform/etc., but I'm not sure where this issue stems from. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must have parented with the *With Automatic Weights* mode, therefore some vertices of the body will be assigned to the vertex group that will be controlled by the arm.

Maybe you should use the *With Empty Groups* mode, that is used for objects, machines, etc.

Once you've parented *With Empty Groups*, the mesh has now a series of vertex groups that have the same name as the bones, but none of the vertices have been assigned to any of these vertex groups, it's up to you to decide which vertices will be part of which vertex group: Just select the vertices, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the vertex group these vertices are supposed to be part of and click on the *Assign* button.

For the 2 kind of "hip" bones, that are supposed to bend the body (?), you could select the body vertices in *Edit* mode (don't select the head and limbs), switch to *Object* mode, select the armature, shift select the object, switch it to *Weight Paint* mode, on the top left of the 3D view click on the *Paint Mask* option (cube icon), shift select the 2 bones, and in the top header menu > *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*.